# Selecting photo from gallery for CircleImageView

Tags: java, gallery

Hi I am new to java and android studio and have followed some tutorials to get images from the gallery and display it in a circular image view.

here is my code:

```
private void openImageFrom() {

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CODE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        avatar.setImageURI(imageUri);



    }
}
```

The problem is that the circleImageView moves based on the image. I need it to stay in its fixed position. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

I am using this dependency in module:app:

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
```

And this is my XML

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_avatar"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/DarkGreen"
    app:civ_border_overlay="true"
    app:civ_border_width="12dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

woops fixed my own issue nevermind.

changed XML:

```
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="350dp"
```